# Horizontal center text with respect to parent container width?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center some text in a div horizontally.

CSS:

```
#parent {
      background-color: #eee;
      height: 48px;
      text-align: center;
}
#colLeft {
      background-color: #ff8b8b;
      height: 48px;
      display: inline;
      float: left;
}
#colRight {
      background-color: #c3d0ff;
      height: 48px;
      display: inline;
      float: right;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="parent" style="width:100%">
      <div id="colLeft">left left left left</div>
      Title
      <div id="colRight">right</div>
 </div>

 <div style="width:100%; text-align:center">
      Title - this one is really centered.
 </div>
```

But it the text "Title" appears to get centered taking into account the space that `#colLeft` consumes, so it's not really centered with respect to the browser width.

Is there a way that I can truly center the text, no matter how much space `#colLeft` takes up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really recommended, but you could do something like this [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rb6en/).

```
#parent {
      background-color: #eee;
      height: 48px;
      text-align: center;
}
#colLeft {
      background-color: #ff8b8b;
      height: 48px;
      display: inline;
      float: left;
}
#colRight {
      background-color: #c3d0ff;
      height: 48px;
      display: inline;
      float: right;
}
.title{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -50px;
}

<div id="parent" style="width:100%">
      <div id="colLeft">left left left left</div>
    <div class="title">Title</div>
      <div id="colRight">right</div>
 </div>

 <div style="width:100%; text-align:center">Title - this one is really centered.</div>​
```

You make the title `position:absolute`. Give it a width. `left: 50%`. `margin-left:` minus half of the width. It will stay center. But I wouldn't really recommend doing this...

Answer (score 1):

if you surround Title with a div like this:

```
<div style="position: absolute;left: 50%">Title</div>
```

You're good in Webkit.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div align="left" style="border:5px solid white; text-align:center; position:relative">

<div align="left" style="border:4px solid brown; float:left; width:100px; position:absolute"><span>left</span></div>
<div align="left" style="border:4px solid brown; right:0; width:200px; position:absolute"><span>right</span></div>

<span>really centered</span></div>
```